# How to generate routes that follow underlying road network?

Tags: qgis, carto, routing, transit

I have a set of points (~2300 bus stops) and I have a network of roads that these bus stops lie on. When I have a bus route that goes from A to B, how do I generate the route such that it follows the underlying road and not just the direct crowfly distance.

[image]

The road data is from OSM and the stop data is user generated. 
At present the data is hosted on :[routemaster.hydlab.in](http://routemaster.hydlab.in)

Comment: have you tried linear referencing ? http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/lrs/

Answer (score 2):

You could try [my routing script for QGIS Processing](http://anitagraser.com/2013/10/19/a-routing-script-for-the-processing-toolbox/) based on the core network analysis library. It expects a point layer and a network layer as input and returns a route between the points.:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Modifiy this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212469/qgis-script-vectorwriter-error/212474#212474 to make it work. Then it works awesomely great; even though oneways are not taken into account.