# QGIS Script - VectorWriter error

Tags: qgis, python, vector

I am running a QGIS network script called "Transit-tools-QGIS" on QGIS 2.12.3

I am interested in this script for my network:

https://github.com/chourmo/QGIS-Transit-tools/blob/master/scripts/Shortest%20paths%20-%20car.py

I get the error:

```
No module named VectorWriter.
```

Can anyone advise me on this issue? I am also a qgis newb.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the existing line:

```
from processing.core.VectorWriter import VectorWriter
```

with this one:

```
from processing.tools.vector import VectorWriter
```